How to send SES analytics to custom endpoint
I'm using AWS SES to send emails. But I want the analytics by user, not for all emails delivered. I want to know which user clicked on the link, which user opened the email, etc. Is there any way to do this?

You'd need to set up SNS notifications and store the data on your end. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/open-and-click-tracking-have-arrived/
